# Is it couple or couples?

Tags: word-choice

In a sentence like the one in the example, do you say both couple or both couples if you are referring to two people in a relationship separately?

> Ex: Both *couple* work at the same bank or  Both *couples* work at the
>   same bank

Comment: **Neither one.**

Comment: You don't need *both*. "The couple work at the same bank." "The recently poisoned couple were being treated at the same hospital that cared for the Skripals." https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/07/world/europe/uk-novichok-poison.html

Answer (score 2):

**Couple** is a collective noun. It takes a singular form and refers to two people.

So, *one couple* comprises *two people* and *two couples* comprise *four people*.

In a sentence, the subject-verb agreement follows the singularity or plurality of the word **couple** itself—not the people who compose it.

So, there are two ways of expressing your example sentence:

> 1. Both *couples work* at the same bank.
> 2. Each *couple works* at the same bank.

---

**Update**: Based on a comment, the sentence may also be talking about one of the individuals within a couple.

Let's say that Bob and Mary form a couple, and Emma and Mike form another couple. Bob and Emma both work at the same bank.

If we know their names:

> Bob and Emma work at the same bank.

Otherwise, we could say:

> 1. Each couple has a member who works at the same bank.
> 2. Both couples have a member who works at the same bank.
> 3. From among each couple, there is an individual who works at the bank.

If you are talking about families in which couples work:

> 1. In our family, both of us work.
> 2. Between us, we both work.
> 3. All of these families have fully working couples.
> 4. Within these family-based couples, both members have a job.

With a *single* couple, you can't refer to *both* couples working because there is only one couple. You have to refer to individuals or members, or use some other term that singles out one of the people in the couple from the other. (If you know the couple, use a name.)

> 1. Bob and Mary both work at the same bank.
> 2. Both members of this couple work at the same bank.

---

Of course, if you are actually referring to a single couple as a collective whole, then the other answer gave a common way of doing so (although there may be a difference between common US and UK English when it comes to subject-verb agreement with collective nouns):

> That couple works at the bank.

There is no need to say *at the* ***same*** *bank* because the couple as a whole is treated as a single unit; each member does the same thing when referenced in this way.

Comment: Jason, I get this much. My question is not about what verb form but more the quantity, if this makes sense.

Comment: @user191110 No, not exactly. Between the two example sentences you gave, your second one would be the one I'd used. (I mentioned it as my first example.) Are you perhaps talking about an individual from one couple and an individual from a different couple?

Comment: No. I'm actually talking about two people in a relationship taken separately. And the fuller sentence I'm trying to clarify is: "In families where (both?) couple work ..."

Comment: @user191110 I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Sounds all so involved the differentiating and all, but I get you. Thanks.

Comment: I'd almost agree with Jason, but "Each couple works at the same bank" spoiled everything.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What do you think the question was asking for? Originally, I had thought it was talking about two couples (four people), all working at one bank. Then I updated my answer based on it being something else (one person from each couple). As well as some other possibilities. Is there another variation that you are interpreting it as?

Comment: I glanced at the introduction and concentrated on the example. 

Looking again, “two people in a relationship separately” seems impenetrable without further context, which the example doesn’t provide.

Equally, neither “Both couple work at the same bank” nor “Both couples work at the same bank” can even refer to “two people in a relationship separately”.

To me either the whole thing completely fails or four people work at the same bank…

(Doubly interesting as I once knew Rita and Peter who both worked at Someplace, and years later met Reet and Pete who worked at that same place.)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin So, wait. Are you saying that *the couple work(s) at the bank* (depending on UK or US usage) is also wrong? Because then I can't understand your scenario. Were Rita and Peter a couple or individuals from two different couples?

Comment: I've no problem with "the couple work(s) at the bank"… only the OQ and "Each couple works at the same bank".… and FYI Rita and Peter were one couple, Reet and Pete another, all four working at one place.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Okay, good. (I did give that at the end of my answer.) My problem was never understanding the exact scenario that was being described. I had originally interpreted it differently than you—and, honestly, I'm still not sure what the intended interpretation is. But I think I've covered all possibilities . . . ;)

Answer (score -1):

Neither. It would be "The couple...".

You can't use couple to refer to two people in a relationship separately, the noun [couple](https://www.etymonline.com/word/couple) originates from the Latin word 'copula' which means "link" or "tie" that connects 2 things together. So you can't say both couples (unless you mean 2 different couples), but *both persons* if you want to specify 2 separate individuals that work at a bank but aren't necessarily connected to each other:

> Both persons work at the same bank

It is not:

> *Both person work at the same bank

However, you can say:

> A couple work at the same bank

or

> The couple work at the same bank

Comment: That’s not entirely correct. “Couple” is a collective noun—if you use it with a singular verb, then “couple” becomes singular. If you use “couple” with a plural verb, then “couple” becomes plural. For instance, one can say, “The married couple is coming over for dinner.” In this sentence, the speaker views the couple as one entity and therefore uses the singular verb *is*. However, one can also say, “The married couple *are* coming over for dinner.” In that sentence, the two people that make up the couple are referred to individually.

Comment: But you are right in saying that “Both couple work at the same bank...” is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, but  whether an is/are is used after collective nouns is a personal choice. British English and American English have different opinions on the matter, in the sense that there is no 'unanimous' rule or 'correct' usage.

Comment: You said: “You can’t use “couple” to refer to two people in a relationship separately...”

Comment: And I believe we are discussing the usage in American English, no?

Comment: @Nathan M. What I said is true. It makes the word plural in the grammatical sense but not in the semantical sense. Regardless of whether is or are is used. In the semantical sense, in that which a couple (the group) will always be singular as it is referring to 2 people collectively.

Comment: Okay. That is true.

Comment: @NathanM. This answer comes closest to addressing my difficulty. My sentence, which I didn't want to reproduce exactly cos it comes from an unpublished work, reads more like this: "In families where both couple work 9-5 jobs . . ." I don't actually have a problem with the verb to use cos I understand that a couple is two and couples can be anywhere from 2, 4, etc, and so the subject-verb agreement will depend on the number of couples as units.

Comment: It is true that I would say "the couple are coming..." (a bit awkward without the word "married," right?) when referring to them separately. For instance , the couple is coming in a car vs. the couple are coming in two cars. So the answer to my question would be: (In families where) the couple work at the same bank ... Still not sure about dispensing with the word "both." Would have thought it helps make things clearer?

Comment: I think you completely side-stepped the point and either way no, you may not say “A couple work at the same bank” except in very special circumstances.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin what are you talking about? That's the circumstance in which the OP described.  ***"This answer comes closest to addressing my difficulty".***

Comment: @aesking - please explain how anything like "This answer comes closest to addressing my difficulty" could be helpful.